# Export Model Textures Per Face

Tags: texture, 3d, uv-mapping, model

(Note that as far as attempts go, I can't find anything that helps me)

I have a 3D polygon, and for simplicity's sake it's going to be the one below:

[image: Basic Textured Polygon]

It is textured using the UV map below:

[image: Basic Texture UV]

*Side Note: I just found the texture on Google. It is not being used in any manner other than solely to demonstrate my question.*

I plan on 3D printing the polygon. Since I suck at painting, I want to print the textures for each face so I can glue/decal them onto the correct faces.

My question is: How can I go from a UV texture map to individual polygon faces (and 1 texture per face) that is correctly scaled to fit the face. I want something like below:

[image: Desired Outcome]

Is there **any** way to do this? I don't care about width * height as I can manage that on my own, but I need the textures to be distorted just like how they are on the corresponding face of the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Since UV coordinates are per a vertex this can be done by simply displaying the 2D UV coords in screen space and texture the resulting triangles using the same texture coords. Since UV coords are usually [0,1] they will need to be rescaled  for the image, but that is also very easy to do.

Here is a image showing the results. This also is showing the triangles that map to the uv coords.
[image]

In the example image the author is showing the mappings of the triangles onto the texture. But it is easy to break up the image, rescale, ect.

Answer (score 0):

UV mapping assigns fixed positions in the texture to each vertex. You'll have to distort the image so that it maps to a constant area in "model size" so to speak. I found the following other question that will probably give you a solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22872/unwrap-uv-map-proportionally-to-object-size

It won't give disjointed parts like in your image, but I think it will still provide what you're looking for.